# How to run plotly library in colab R

Tags: r, plotly, google-colaboratory

I am using R in google colaboratory. I want to use ploly library, but it does not provide graph.
I am using the following code:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)

fig
```

It gives me the output

```
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'scatter' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter

No scatter mode specifed:
  Setting the mode to markers
  Read more about this attribute -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-mode

No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'scatter' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter

No scatter mode specifed:
  Setting the mode to markers
  Read more about this attribute -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-mode
```

and no graph is provided.
Is it possible to use plotly in R colab?